# Excel Row Majority Voting

Tags: excel, vba

I have a excel file with value that are between 1 and 8, this is the first two lines of my file. 
I would like to create a new column that return the value with the highest occurence for each row 
For example you can see here in the 1st row 3 has the highest occurence so I return 3 in the second it's 7 ...

```
3   3   3   3   4   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   *3*
7   6   6   7   7   6   7   7   7   8   6   7   *7*
```

Could you help me please

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This formula work also 
=MODE(A1:L1)

Comment: I can't believe I forgot about MODE().  Good catch.  Make sure you mark this as correct when you can.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with the excel formula max highest value in row 1 is 4 en for row 2 is it

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=MATCH(1, IF(COUNTIF(A1:L1,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8})=MAX(COUNTIF(A1:L1,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8})),1,0),0)
```

Or this one:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((COUNTIF(A1:L1,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8})=MAX(COUNTIF(A1:L1,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8})))*{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8})
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks for your anwser but, I have error with your formula

Comment: @user3351370 what error?  I promise, the picture is not photoshopped.  Are your number actual numbers or text that look like numbers?